# Insert new field to JSON file

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-7

How can I insert or add a new Field to JSON file ? I'm using lkjson btw.

```
var
  js: TlkJSONobject;
  val : String;
begin
  js := TlkJSONstreamed.loadfromfile(jsonFile) as TlkJsonObject;
  try
    try
      val := js.Field['users'].Field[username].Field[value5].Value; //field value5 doesnt exist
    except
      //add field

    end;
    TlkJSONstreamed.SaveToFile(js, jsonFile);
  finally
    js.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: if you want this lazy approach with implicit creation I think you should use SuperObject library instead. While it might be somewhat slower.  / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790006 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731833

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
(js.Field['users'].Field[username] as TlkJSONobject).Add(value5, '1');
```

Where `users` and `username` do exist.

Comment: Since the data may not be exactly as you expect, checked type cast should be preferred, replace `TlkJSONobject(...)` with `(... as TlkJSONobject)`.

Comment: @DavidH you truly said that Master O:-)